# Check if city is lies on route obtained from Google Directions API API

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I need to check if a particular city will be passed by when going through road obtained from Google Directions API.

I have made an assumption that passing through some cities will require you to take toll roads. I'm making an online service that calculates driving cost based on distance and toll road costs.

For ferries Google API is giving start-end cities. Based on these city names i can detect which ferry will be taken and add costs to the whole driving cost.
There's a problem when taking in example a paid bridge.

Example:
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Londyn,+Wielka+Brytania&daddr=Slagelse,+Dania&hl=pl&ll=55.27364,11.125031&spn=0.621154,1.473541&sll=49.21042,-34.892578&sspn=45.846455,94.306641&geocode=Fa7_EQMd8Cv-_yl13iGvC6DYRzGZKtXdWjqWUg%3BFaxkTQMdeUStACm3zdTgYmFNRjEAD68T8wkEvw&oq=Lond&t=h&mra=ls&z=10

Road from Slagelse, Denmark to London, goes through a paid bridge between Korsor and Nyborg (about 70GBP toll), however in directions this road chunk is defined as:

```
[7]=>
            object(stdClass)#640 (7) {
              ["distance"]=>
              object(stdClass)#641 (2) {
                ["text"]=>
                string(6) "128 km"
                ["value"]=>
                int(127914)
              }
              ["duration"]=>
              object(stdClass)#642 (2) {
                ["text"]=>
                string(14) "1 hour 11 mins"
                ["value"]=>
                int(4257)
              }
              ["end_location"]=>
              object(stdClass)#643 (2) {
                ["lat"]=>
                float(55.545784)
                ["lng"]=>
                float(9.524455)
              }
              ["html_instructions"]=>
              string(115) "Turn <b>right</b> to merge onto <b>E20</b> toward <b>Odense</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Partial toll road</div>"
```

How could i check if either Korsor or Nyborg is on the road? 
Or should i just assume that paid E20 road always contains that bridge?

Comment: Yeah you could just watch for either `<b>E20</b>` and/or `toll road`.  However many toll roads and bridges only operate in one direction, which might spoil that technique!

Comment: You need access to a database of toll roads, ferries and associated costs which is going to be difficult because Channel ferry prices vary by time of day, day of year, vehicle size and so forth.